# Regular Expressions in PHP

Tags: php, regex

Sorry for unclear description, my English is not good.

My problem is that I want to decode a string, and this string has nested content delimited by {}.
For example:

The string:

```
{any string0{any string 00{any string 000....}}}{any string1}any string.
```

The result I want to get:

```
 array[0] = {any string0{any string 00{any string 000....}}}
 array[1] = {any string1}
```

I hope it's clear enough.

Comment: You cannot do this using regular expressions.

Comment: Try to explain your problem better, it's very hard to understand what you need to do

Comment: kindly try editing your post. use the 'code sample' feature. thanks!

Comment: You need to pry the parser out of the speak and spell to accomplish this.

Answer (score 4):

Making the best use of the (oddly put, and hopefully soon-to-be-edited) question, the following takes your example string and provides your example array.

```
$subject = '{blah\blah{\blah\blah...{\bl....}}}{blah...}blah... ';
$pattern = '/\{(?>[^{}]++|(?R))*\}/';

preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Which produces:

```
Array
(
    [0] => {blah\blah{\blah\blah...{\bl....}}}
    [1] => {blah...}
)
```